# Similarity between two curves

Tags: excel, regression, correlation, similarity, curve

I have two curves, one shows delay and another one shows distance between an origin node and a set of destinations. Here I define similarity between two curves as follow:

"If two curves fluctuate like each other, they are similar."

For instance, the following example shows delay and distance numbers:

```
delay (ms):   10   2   4
dist (miles): 100  50  200
```

In this example, these two curves are 100% similar, **because whenever delay increased (decreased), distance increased (decreased), regardless of how much**.

Now I am wondering whether you know any formula or function (e.g. in **Excel**) that can compare two curves, as described.

P.S. I know about "correlation coefficient", but it takes into account the gap between two points so it is not exactly what I want.

Edit:
Here are some real samples of my datasets:

```
Delay(ms)   Distance (miles)
13.518      616.5446819
21.263      1933.776108
12.616      724.7038212
12.549      5498.406764
141.845     5632.345229
46.993      724.7038212
12.5        753.1841094
12.691      5781.96039
42.506      1891.116399
54.681      1701.703208
13.935      2264.365699
183.754     6000.673799
41.23       1905.88337
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data?  What did you find in the research that you've done so far?  Once you figure out the formula, it should be straightforward to myself or someone else to plug into Excel.  Based on the sample data you gave it seems pretty simple, just compare (A/B) to (C/D) to (E/F)... but I assume it's not that east or you wouldn't be here?  What kind of curves are you dealing with?  Also please check out [mcve]

Comment: Well, as I said I have two datasets, one for delay and another one for distance. However, as you mentioned it not as easy as the provided example. Actually, there are thousands of records in each datasets, so I am wondering how can I find out their similarities in a fastest way.

Comment: Well let's see this data then.  (or some of it, or if the data is secret, then you'll have to find a way to generate some data to test with.)  As it stands there is no way to help you.

Comment: I don't see any curves here, just datapoints, and let's *not* confuse one for the other. If you're testing for similar increase/decrease (without regard of magnitude) then: just do that. For each point i>0 take data[i] and data[i-1], compute the sign of their difference, and see if the signs match between data=delay and data=distance. There are no curves here.